# Why does the generator loss diverge in my WGAN-GP

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am using a WGAN-GP for medical image generation and while training, I notice that the loss for the generator diverges to a high value while the loss for the discriminator is more or less the same as the training continues - [Loss plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj2zQ.jpg). I am not sure why that would happen.

I am using [this](https://github.com/aladdinpersson/Machine-Learning-Collection/tree/master/ML/Pytorch/GANs/4.%20WGAN-GP) code for the WGAN-GP. The only thing I changed in this implementation was to change the number of filters in the discriminator to 32 (or ngf/4).

Comment: The thing to keep in mind is that diverging generator loss doesn't necessarily mean your model is not learning. Since you're training in an adversarial manner, it is possible that images generated by your model get closer to the real distribution, while your generator loss diverges since all the while your discriminator learns the real distribution faster than your generator. One thing to check is to have your generator save some samples every n epochs and check them to see if you're model is actually learning. If you're model is not learning, you might need to tweak some hyper-parameters.